# UnauthorizedAccessException VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I created a simple console application for the retrieval of files from an FTP site. Everything worked perfectly. I then decided that I wanted to set it as a windows service so that it will run in the background on a scheduled interval. When I made the change to set it as a service I then encountered an *UnauthroizedAccessException* in the form of *Access to the path ... is denied.* Is it as simple as giving folder access to a service account? I've given full rights to the *Everyone* user but no luck. I'm at a loss with this.

Thanks for the help.

Jonathan

Comment: Try changing the user account under which the service runs.  Try setting it to your own account, for instance, just to see if that works.

Comment: @Steven If I look at the Task Manager as the program is running, the process tab shows that the user is my account. Is this what you're talking about?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.  You can set it to any user you wish via the service's properties dialog under the services control panel.

Comment: @Steven Any other ideas since it shows to be running under my account?

Comment: Do you have a call stack for the exception?  If not, you need to get it.  Once you have that, you'll be able to determine which line in your code is failing.  If you can't figure it out from there, you should post the pertinent code so we can see what you are doing and where, exactly, it's failing.